# MYSQL query problem - can't figure it out

Tags: php, mysql

Hy, i have a big question ... it may sound simple but actually it's very complicated

I have two mysql tables :

```
info_cat (id, name)
info_subcat (id, id_info_cat, name)
```

I want to show the user the `info_cat.name` followed by `info_subcat.name` but the problem is that `info_cat.name` i want to appear just one time. 
Something like this:

Laptop

- Hp
- Sony
- Acer

HDD

- Western DIgital
- Seagate
- ETC

So normaly i will query like this (old fashioned)

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM info_cat");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
$id_info_cat = $row['id'];
echo $row['name']; 
 $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM info_subcat WHERE id_info_cat = '$id_info_cat'");
 while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query2)) {
 echo $row2['nume'];
 }
}
```

and i have `while within while`.
My question is how can i use only a query to acomplish this (i think with JOIN) ??
I have tried the following command :

```
SELECT info_cat.name, info_subcat.name AS name2, info_subcat.id FROM info_cat, info_subcat WHERE info_cat.id = info_subcat.id_info_cat;
```

but can't figure it out how to manipulate data because it will output :

```
name       name2                 id
Laptop     Acer                  1
Laptop     HP                    2
Laptop     Sony                  3
HDD        Western Digital       4
HDD        Seagate               5
HDD        ETC                   6
```

and i just want to echo Laptop one time and HDD one time followed by its subcat names.
How can i do that ?

Pleaseee ....

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you just echo Laptop one time and HDD one time?

Comment: What ? If you see my question i mentioned that using the second query it will output a lot of times because HDD has only a record in info_cat but it contains many id links in info_subcat.. :(

Comment: what I meant was that, if you have that table (2nd query). You could echo just the first occurrence of Laptop and not the others and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using GROUP BY and GROUP_CONCAT.

```
SELECT
    info_cat.name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(info_subcat.name ORDER BY info_subcat.name SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM
    info_cat
        LEFT JOIN
    info_subcat ON (info_car.id = info_subcat.id_info_cat)
GROUP BY
    info_cat.id
```

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT is in my opinion one of the most useful often forgotten functions :). If it suits your needs accept it as an answer.

Comment: but why i need to use GROUP BY ... if i don;t use it the script generates only one line ... why ? And another question ... for every info_subcat i have different id`s that i want to have ... i need to group_concat them as well ?

Comment: It gives you only one line because it then concats all the rows because you haven't specified any grouping criteria. What do you mean by different IDs?

Comment: this will break for subcategories containing a comma in their name (if you use another character instead of `, ` it will break for this other character …)

Comment: i have `info_subcat(id, id_info_cat, name)` ... and info_subcat.id is autoincremented ... and  i also need that individual id .. when concating i have `(name1, name2, name3, name4)` ... and i want to use the different id`s to send ajax request and retrive info for that `info_subcat.name` ...  basically they are 3 levels .. i will create another table `info_text(id, id_info_subcat, text)`

Comment: knittl: it won't break... Why would it? There will just be one more comma (as part of the name).

Comment: pufos: sorry, Karaoke was stronger than me so I had to go. Well if you want to have the id as part of the resulting string you can just do something like GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('(', info_subcat.id, ') ', info_subcat.name) ORDER BY info_subcat.name SEPARATOR ', ') or you can just concat the IDs in a new column as GROUP_CONCAT(info_subcat.id ORDER BY info_subcat.name SEPARATOR ', ').

Comment: Thank you very much .. I appreciate your effort .. Thanks

Comment: @kaltas: if you then split in php on all `,` it will break. at least i'm pretty sure it will

Comment: Oh then it definitely would but that depends on what pufos wants to do with it. This is only good for printing out of course.

Answer (score 2):

there's nothing wrong with having nested while loops, when they describe the problem perfectly (a list within a list). if however, you want to avoid nested while loops at all costs, you can do the following:

```
$query = mysql_query("
     SELECT ic.name ic_name, isc.name isc_name
       FROM info_cat ic
  LEFT JOIN info_subcat isc
         ON ic.id = isc.id_info_cat
   ORDER BY ic_name ASC");

$last_cat = '';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
  if($row['ic_name'] != $last_cat) {
    echo $row['ic_name']; 
    $last_cat = $row['ic_name'];
  }
  echo $row['name'];
}
```

it should be possible to write the above query without the `ORDER BY` statement, which gains you a little bit of performance. using `ORDER BY` is a little bit more explicit and guarantees (the SQL standards do not dictate a certain ordering of rows, could be anything) the correct ordering and output of the result set (although mysql usually does what you expect).

Comment: This would require an order by on cat names

Comment: @tandu: not necessarily, because mysql will not reorder the first table during the join operation (so, ic_names will always be grouped together). nevertheless added for clarity and to avoid cornercase bugs that might occur

Comment: Agreed not necessarily, but when in software engineering can we accept a "not necessarily" when there is such a trivial solution? :)

Comment: @tandu: `ORDER BY` performs not very well in sql, so it's good to avoid it, when not necessary. even if it performed well, it's additional computational overhead

Comment: MySQL will choose its order depending on the engine if none is specified and you cannot depend on it.  If you `ORDER BY` whatever column MySQL has already picked, the query optimizer will ignore the ORDER BY anyway, so you won't lose performance if it's already what you need.  If it's not already what you need then you need to be using `ORDER BY` anyway.

Comment: all answers are corect and all have something special like GROUP_CONCAT wich is cool .. but for my problem this code works best because i have different ids for subcat entry wich i use to ajax request text fields for them. thank you very much

Comment: @pufos: if this answer works best for you and is the answer to your exact question then you should accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Use group by in your query

```
SELECT info_cat.name, info_subcat.name AS name2, info_subcat.id FROM info_cat inner join info_subcat on info_cat.id = info_subcat.id_info_cat
group by info_cat.name
order by info_cat.name desc
```

Then in your while loop, do an if check to see if an info_cat name = last info_cat name and if they both are equal then don't add it otherwise add it
e.g. (this is psedocode below)

```
$lastInfoCatName = $row['name']; 
while ($row != null)
{
if ($lastInfoCatName != $row['name']
{
$lastInfoCatName = $row['name']
//work on creating the table
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to do this.  For the sake of completion, I'll list both.

**Method #1**

```
$query = <<<SQL
   SELECT
      ic.name catname
      , is.name subcatname
   FROM
      info_cat ic
      JOIN info_subcat is ON (ic.id = is.info_cat_id)
SQL;

$result = mysql_query($query);

$cats = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
   if ( ! isset($cats[$result->catname]) ) {
      $cats[$result->catname] = array();
   }
   $cats[$result->catname][] = $result->subcatname;
}

foreach ($cats as $catname => $subcats) {
   echo "$catname<br /> <ul>";
   foreach ($subcats as $subcat) {
      echo "<li>$subcat</li>";
   }
   echo "</ul>";
}
```

**Method #2**

```
$query = <<<SQL
   SELECT
      ic.name catname,
      GROUP_CONCAT(is.name) subcatnames
   FROM
      info_cat ic
      JOIN info_subcat is ON (ic.id = is.info_cat_id)
SQL;

$result = mysql_query($query);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
   echo "$row->name<br /><ul>"
   foreach (explode(',', $row->subcatnames) as $subcatname) {
      echo "<li>$subcatname</li>";
   }
   echo "</ul>";
}
```

Since everyone else is going to suggest it too, you should use PDO and PHPTAL, and when you are creating a table you should give the "id" column a name that references the table such as "icID" and "isID"

Comment: what about category names with `,`? this will break badly then …

Comment: True, if this is a concern you can pick a better separator.  Or you'll end up with more categories than usual.

Answer (score 0):

The result you've posted looks like a mysql result, not the php output according to your script.

Iterating through the main categories, it will echo the name, and it will iterate through its sub categories and echo the sub names and move on.

There's nowhere in your example where it prodcues such an output...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT info_cat.name, GROUP_CONCAT(info_subcat.name) AS name2
FROM info_cat, info_subcat
WHERE info_cat.id = info_subcat.id_info_cat
GROUP BY info_cat.name;
```

conCAT! :)